# Unicode characters and regex

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am trying to run the following command in Python:

```
data = "&city=Zayas de Báscones;Zayas de Báscones;"
arr = re.findall(ur'[&]{1}\w{4}=[a-zA-ZA-Za-z£€ßçÇáàâäæãåèéêëîïíìôöòóøõûüùúÿñÁÀÂÄÆÃÅÈÉÊËÎÏÍÌÔÖÒÓØÕÛÜÙÚŸÑðÐ]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-ZA-Za-z£€ßçÇáàâäæãåèéêëîïíìôöòóøõûüùúÿñÁÀÂÄÆÃÅÈÉÊËÎÏÍÌÔÖÒÓØÕÛÜÙÚŸÑðÐ]+)*',data)
x = "".join(arr)
x = x.split('&city=')
print x
```

The result:

```
['', 'Zayas de B?scones']
```

How can I get the unicode character instead of the question mark ? I have been trying to use the regex pattern with a 'u' character at the start of the string (e.g: u'pattern') and also 'ur' before the patttern.

Comment: Your input is not Unicode. It is a encoded bytestring. What encoding is used for that bytestring?

Comment: Why does your character class list `A-Z` and `a-z` twice each?

Comment: Also, why not use [`urlparse.parse_qs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) to parse query strings?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - sorry, I don't understand you. The  problematic word is:Báscones. The A-Z and a-z are written twice because I want to regex city names, such as: New-York, New York and also city names with unicode charachters.

Comment: Your input value is a bytestring, not a unicode value. Even if your editor or terminal or console is showing the `á` character directly, it could be encoded in UTF-8 (as two bytes, C3 A1) or as Latin 1, (the byte E1), or any number of other bytes or combination of bytes. Not decoding it properly is what is causing your problem here.

Comment: The `[...]` character class in a regular expression is a *set*, you only need to name characters part of the class once. Using `a-zA-Z` means all characters in those ranges are included. Naming them *again* doesn't change what the class will match.

Comment: Also, the accented characters in the character class look suspiciously like the Latin-1 alphabetics. If you want to actually handle Unicode, the set of valid Latin alphabetics is much, much larger. In Unicode, you can write Ůńıĉőđē.

Comment: (Also, why do you have ð but not þ?)

Comment: @HankSmith, why not use `[\w£€$]` with the `re.U` flag to catch all word chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to print `x[1]`:

```
 print x[1]
 #output: Zayas de B?
```

Now if you treat your `data` string as unicode.

```
data = u"&city=Zayas de Báscones;Zayas de Báscones;" # set it as unicode
```

If you try to print `x[1]`:

```
print x[1]
#output: Zayas de Báscones
```

Comment: I assume `data` comes from an HTTP query string. Make sure the data is decoded correctly into a Unicode(Python 2.x) or string (Python 3) object